# node-sqlite insert fails on not-null constraint, but data are there?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express, promise

I've got the following code in my nodejs app as part of an expressjs service:

```
let db = sqlite.open(conf.database, { Promise }).then( (dba) => {
    P.all([dba.exec(accesslog_ddl),dba.exec(tokens_ddl)]).then(()=>{
        console.log("Database initialized ...");
    });
    return dba;
});

let upsertToken = function (token, expire, customer) {
    return db.then(d=>{
        console.log(`${token}, ${expire}, ${customer}`);
        return d.exec("insert into tokens (tokenid, name, email, cell, expire) values (?,?,'none','none','never')",
            [token,expire]);
    });
};

// ... expressjs setup ...

router.post('/tokens',(req,res) => {
    tokens.addToken(req.body.token, req.body.expires, req.body.name)
    .then(() => {res.status(201).send()})
    .catch((e) => {res.status(500).send(e)});
});
```

The output in the logs is as follows:

```
bluhbleh, never, fred flintstone
{ [Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: NOT NULL constraint failed: tokens.name] errno: 19, code: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT' }
POST /services/tokens 500 20.287 ms - 2
```

This proves that `token`, `expire`, and `customer` are all present prior to the `exec()` call, yet the call fails due to a NOT NULL constraint failure.

A few odd things about this code:

1. I'm using the promisified [node-sqlite package](https://github.com/kriasoft/node-sqlite).
2. I'm using a promisified [expressjs router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-promise-router).
3. I really am new to promises (and nodejs generally), and am probably not doing something right.

My full code is here:
https://bitbucket.org/highaltitudearchery/locker/src/master/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `exec` wrong.  The [promisified](https://github.com/kriasoft/node-sqlite/blob/f16f8b3fe28a09b0134bbed9dc9e39bba11a23ad/src/Database.js#L99) version of [Database#exec](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseexecsql-callback) only takes a single argument, the SQL to execute.

Comment: D'oh! Missed that. Odd that exec doesn't allow parameterized sql.  Switched to `.run()` and now working much better.